# When to use broadcast vs. addfile in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

It looks like addfile and broadcast do similar things. How are they different? When should you use one vs. the other?

Answer (score 1):

**Broadcast is used for variables** that you need in your code, it could be a static list that is required to be referred by each task, from the documentation of [Broadcast Variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html)

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable
>   cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks.
>   They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large
>   input dataset in an efficient manner. Spark also attempts to
>   distribute broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to
>   reduce communication cost.

**Add file is used to make a file** available on every node, it could be a jar file or a library that program refers.

Hoping this clarifies.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Addfile adds a file to the spark. It generally used to load local files to spark.

Where as broadcast is the concept of joining 2 datasets in spark. In case one of the RDD/DataFrame is small it can be broadcasted to all the executors so that it can do map join.

Addfile knows from where to load the file but in case of broadcast the underlying file could be distributed but the dataframe created on top of the distributed files could be small. This can be achieved through filtering / transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Typical usecases:

```
 Use Broadcast for variables / data.

 Use addFile for libraries / custom code etc.
```

There are exceptions to both though, in cases there is huge data ( in my case it was ~900MB ) I used the addFile mechanism to pass on the file to all nodes and then load the data there. This proved to be working a bit faster as my file was already in gzipped format.